# How to get a right character when we use cmd command

Tags: character-encoding, command-line

This is my runtime environment

```
$Version
$CharacterEncoding
```

> "11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 16, 2017)"
>
> "CP936"

When I run

```
SetDirectory["C:/Windows/AppPatch"];
RunProcess["cmd", "StandardOutput", "dir\n"]
```

I get a such output

[image]

I know the wrong character is Chinese character. How to show it correctlly?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First method:

```
run[cmdLine_] := Module[{out}, 
                RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "/c", cmdLine <> ">test.txt"}]["StandardOutput"];
                out = Import["test.txt", CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"];
                DeleteFile["test.txt"]; out]

run["echo 你好"]
```

> "你好"

```
run["dir"]
```

[image]

**Second method:**

```
Import["!echo hello 你好", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"]
```

> "hello 你好"

```
Import["!dir\n", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"]
(*also works*)
```

Answer (score 0):

More cleaner. Just make a note here.

```
ImportString[
 RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", "dir\n"], "Text", 
 CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"]
```

Comment: It isn't clear for what purpose you use `FromCharacterCode` here: `ImportString` already returns a grid of strings. It would be more correct to specify `"Text"` as second argument to `ImportString`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks very much. It works indeed..And I have updated it just now.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Another thing about it, Since `ImportString // Options` don't include option `CharacterEncoding`, but we can use it. It is a bug of `ImportString`?

Comment: The `CharacterEncoding` option is listed on the [Docs page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Text.html) for the `"Text"` import format, there is no bug of course.